# How can I get the checkin comment/message in TFS Build Definition?

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to get the checkin comment/message in a TFS 2013 build definition (work flow file)? I have looked in `BuildDetail` but haven't found it.

Answer (score 1):

Comment is a property a of a [Changeset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.changeset.aspx). You can access the comment by querying the changesets. The snippet below when added after the `AssociateChangesetsAndWorkItems` activity of the default template, loops through all changesets (`associatedChangesets`) and prints each changeset (`cs`) comment.

```
<ForEach x:TypeArguments="mtvc:Changeset" DisplayName="ForEach&lt;Changeset&gt;" Values="[associatedChangesets]">
  <ActivityAction x:TypeArguments="mtvc:Changeset">
    <ActivityAction.Argument>
      <DelegateInArgument x:TypeArguments="mtvc:Changeset" Name="cs" />
    </ActivityAction.Argument>
    <mtbwa:WriteBuildMessage Message="[String.Format(&quot;Changeset {0}: {1}&quot;, cs.ChangesetId, cs.Comment)]" />
  </ActivityAction>
</ForEach>
```

Comment: `Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "associatedChangesets".
'associatedChangesets' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.`

Am I missing something? Did I need to add an `associatedChangesets` variable somewhere? I copied/pasted the code you provided directly after the `AssociateChangesetsAndWorkItems`.

Comment: It's part of the default build template (`DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml`).

Answer (score 0):

Comments are associated with Changests and, with the exception of CI builds, you will have multiple check-in per build. Which is the right one?

Comment: I'm looking specifically at CI builds.