# Visual Studio XAML Build Process Template - Get Comment

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, tfs, build

I'm currently creating a custom build process template as part of a Team Foundation Build definition, using Visual Studio 2013.

The builds are set to 'Continuous Integration - Build each check-in' as their trigger, and I'm looking to get some information about the check-in once the build starts running.

So far, I can get the following:
Build number using: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Extensions.WellKnownEnvironmentVariables.BuildNumber
Changeset ID using: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Extensions.WellKnownEnvironmentVariables.SourceGetVersion

These have both been retrieved using 'GetEnvironmentVariable' from the list of 'Team Foundation Build Activities'.

[image]

What I need now is the comment associated with that changeset. So the comment I set during the check-in that triggered the build.

Is this possible?

Comment: What's your requirement ? Did you just want your comment during the check in trigger the build? Instead of  check in action trigger the build ?

Comment: I want the check-in to trigger the build, so that's fine. But the next stage is a 'Run Script' step, which will strip out part of the comment and use it as a variable in some Powershell. So my comment might contain '#100', and that's what I'll strip out and pass to my script.

Comment: As you said, Comment is a property a of a Changeset. You can access the comment by querying the changesets. However, it's not able to do this through build template in "Team Foundation Build Activities'.

Comment: Same as this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21787164/how-can-i-get-the-checkin-comment-message-in-tfs-build-definition, refer to KMoraz's answer for details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the checkin comment/message in TFS Build Definition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21787164/how-can-i-get-the-checkin-comment-message-in-tfs-build-definition)